# Video share not showing on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I using the LinkedIn API to share a video to a company page. I am using this endpoint : https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts

I POST this payload:

```
{
    "author": "urn:li:company:**company_page_id**",
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
    "specificContent": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
            "media": [
                {
                    "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:**my_asset_id_that_is_ready**",
                    "status": "READY",
                    "title": {
                        "text": "A video!"
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "text": "New vid"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "shareCommentary": {
                "text": "A new video!"
            },
            "shareMediaCategory": "VIDEO"
        }
    },
    "visibility": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
    }
}
```

I am getting this back:

```
{
    "id": "urn:li:ugcPost:**a_post_id**"
}
```

However the post is never showing up on the page.

If I use a direct link like this:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:ugcPost:**a_post_id**/
```

Then I get this message:
Something went wrong.
We’re having issues loading the page.

Can anyone help me see what is wrong with this payload?

Comment: What do you receive when you call the get for UGC Posts? It might show a different status than published. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api